# background scrolling together with content

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a form with an A4 image in the background (a standard questionaire). on that form i have textfields to fill. But if we scroll to the bottom of the form, the textfields scroll, but the background does not.  How to fix the background to stick with the texfields ?  VB.NET visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

- Place a panel on the Form.
- Place all your controls inside the panel.
- Set the Background of the panel to your image.
- Size your panel so that it is large enough to hold all the controls.
- Place the panel at 0,0
- Set the Form to AutoScroll

Comment: Thanks Dan-o. I think i did all, but it does not work. Form created. Controls (text fields, all in panel). background also in panel. The background vertically is larger then the panel. So i first sized the panel to fix all textfields on image and then cut it back to fit in the form. scrollbar on the right. Autoscroll on. Text fields are scrolling, but image stay put. must be some little thing. will keep searching.

Comment: The form gets the AutoScroll, not the panel.  The panel should be larger vertically than the form.  The point of this setup is to scroll the panel (and thus everything inside it) instead of scrolling the text fields.

Comment: Thanks Dan-o. It works. I put both on autoscroll. that was the problem. Now the panel is false and the form is true. works fine. Many thanks. Loek